# How to update multiple rows depending on condition in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a database in which suppose i have a table named `Score`  in `Score` there are two fields

1. Id
2. Name

now when i see that there are many names starting with `-` for example

```
-Karl-KSJ
-Jhon-Kate
-Xyz-Abc
```

now i want to remove leading `-` from all rows and update them , and leave all rows where name is not starting with `-` . How can i achieve that in sql . Please mind it that i have millions of records so performance will play a major role .

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this, it's simple, it might be fast enough:

```
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE  Score 
SET     Name = RIGHT(Name, LEN(Name) - 1)
WHERE   LEFT(Name, 1) = '-'

ROLLBACK
```

Here is an **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e082/2/0)**